# How do you remove the column name row when exporting a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, header

Say I import the following Excel spreadsheet into a dataframe:

```
Val1 Val2 Val3
1     2    3 
5     6    7 
9     1    2
```

How do I delete the column name row (in this case `Val1, Val2, Val3`) so that I can export a csv with no column names, just the data?

I have tried `df.drop()` and `df.ix[1:]` and have not been successful with either.

Comment: The *'column name row'* is called the *'header'*. Most read/write commands like `to_csv()` have an option `header` to control it, e.g. `header = None`

Answer (score 223, accepted):

You can write to csv without the header using `header=False` and without the index using `index=False`. If desired, you also can modify the separator using `sep`.

CSV example with no header row, omitting the header row:

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv', header=False)
```

TSV (tab-separated) example, omitting the index column:

```
df.to_csv('filename.tsv', sep='\t', index=False)
```

Answer (score 37):

Figured out a way to do this:

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv', header = False)
```

This tells pandas to write a csv file without the header. You can do the same with df.to_excel.

Comment: No, [the option was changed to  `header=None` way back in pandas 0.17 (2015)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/whatsnew.html#changes-to-bool-passed-as-header-in-parsers)

Comment: @smci You might be thinking of `read_csv`. For `to_csv` the type for the `header` parameter is `bool or list of str, default True`

Answer (score 5):

If you pass header=False, you will get this error

```
TypeError: Passing a bool to header is invalid. Use header=None 
for no header or header=int or list-like of ints to specify the 
row(s) making up the column names
```

Instead, use header=None

Comment: This no longer seems to be true.

Comment: [The option was changed to  `header=None` way back in pandas 0.17 (2015)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/whatsnew.html#changes-to-bool-passed-as-header-in-parsers)

Comment: It's been changed back at some point. header=False works for pandas 1.1.1