# Python pandas dict to csv with one header only

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data in a dict that I would like to save as an csv file with pandas:

```
data = {
        "a": 1,
        "c": 2,
        "d": 3,
       }
```

Which I am trying to save it in this format:

[image]

I am doing this with:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])
data.to_csv(path, mode='a', columns=None, header=list(data.keys()))
```

After `data` is saved, I will have more entries (dict) that are in the same format as `data` that I need to append to the same csv file. Let's suppose I have:

```
data2 = {
        "a": 2,
        "c": 3,
        "d": 4,
       }
```

I need to append it as this:

[image]

But if I ran the same code with `data2`, the headers will be displayed again:

[image]

Is there a way to automatically add the header if it is the first entry, and for subsequent entries, no header will be added with the same code. I cannot detect in my code which data is the first entry.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you remove the column name row when exporting a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781609/how-do-you-remove-the-column-name-row-when-exporting-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: It sounds like you know which headers will be in your CSV, in which case I'd suggest you save the CSV without any headers, then add the headers when you need to read  the table in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only add the headers if the file does not exist:

```py
import pandas
import os

data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0], 'b': [1]})
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2], 'b': [3]})
path = './data.csv'

data.to_csv(path, mode='a', header=not os.path.exists(path))
data2.to_csv(path, mode='a', header=not os.path.exists(path))
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Use `header=None` after the first export:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0])
data.to_csv(path, mode='a')

data2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, index=[0])
data2.to_csv(path, mode='a', header=None)
```

Output:

```
,a,c,d
0,1,2,3
0,2,3,4
```

Answer (score -1):

To append new data without header just try to set `header=False` for next rows